# Spring MVC: localization in controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, localization

I want to send a localized email from my controller.

My localization is configured and working fine in my Thymeleaf tiles.

My configuration is as follows:

```html
 ...
 <!-- i18n -->
 <bean id="messageSource"
  class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
   <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:messages</value>
                <value>classpath:cpcscorereport</value>
            </list>
        </property>
  <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
 </bean>


<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
  <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
 </bean> 
 
 
 <bean id="handlerMapping"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
  <property name="interceptors">
   <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
  </property>
 </bean>


 <bean id="localeResolver"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
  <property name="defaultLocale" value="zh_CN" />
 </bean>

 ...

</beans>
```

So *theoretically* I autowire message source into the controller as follows:

```
    @Autowired
private ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource;
```

Then access the messages as follows:

```
        String message = messageSource.getMessage("report.title", null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
        SSm.getLogger().debug("localized message:   "+message);
```

BUt I get the following exception at autowire

> 23-Feb-2017 18:19:06.969 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Allocate exception for servlet AssessmentDelivery
>    org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Why is it not picking up the autowired bean in the controller?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using MessageSource instead of ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource

```
@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;
```

Comment: Perfect. I assume that ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource is a proxy or abstract class?